# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File from xml type layout resource ID #0x1020014

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listactivity, android-resources

I'm trying to use an ArrayAdapter in a ListActivity:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.id.text1, new String[] { "a", "b"});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/android:text1" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

None of the solutions I found on StackOverflow seems to work. I'm using API 10. Can you help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a layout for the rows of your ListView, and call it, for example, `simple_list_item_1` (create the file `simple_list_item_1.xml` in the folder `res/layout`). Put your `TextView` into this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and then create your ArrayAdapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.text1, new String[] { "a", "b"});
```

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listactivity_overview) you'll find a detailed explanation about Lists and Adapters.

Comment: This solves the problem - maybe not as straightforward as Sam's suggestion, but you've also shown me how to customize list items. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You are using the wrong type of resource, you need to reference `R.layout` not `R.id`. Try `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "a", "b"});
```

Comment: No, the documentation is clear, the second parameter is the layout. Perhaps you are thinking of [this constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]%29): `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)` where the third parameter is the TextView's id.

Comment: Wow, you're right! How did I miss that? This is actually the easiest way to solve the problem. Too bad I can't accept both answers.